# Aqualung not compiling with specific libraries

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, ffmpeg

I am trying to build the music player Aqualung on a 64-bit lightweight linux based distro called Puppy Linux. I have built all the listed libraries from source and now I am trying to compile [Aqualung](http://aqualung.factorial.hu/compiling.html), but there are problems

1. It fails to build with ffmpeg enabled and
2. Does not detect libmac built from the source in the list

With FFMPEG disabled, I am able to compile it. I did not compile GTK but used the one that came with the distro.

It would be appreciated if someone could give me some insights into this.
Thanks!

Config Log: http://pastebin.com/SYiHahUt

Make Log: http://pastebin.com/aEp96yJ9
logged using `make 2>&1 | tee make.out.log`

Comment: A quick check shows that Aqualung is usually **not** compiled with ffmpeg : Debian : https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/aqualung : No ffmpeg is listed ,,, and Fedora :  `$ grep BuildRequires aqualung.spec` : No fmpeg listed

Comment: @KnudLarsen, please check on the link given above. It shows all the compile options, and ffmpeg is rather clearly mentioned.